# Meta-programming: output method body as text

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I'm dynamically defining a method in a module, and I'd like to check that once the method is bound to a class instance that the body of the method is what I'm expecting.  Is there a way to output (as text) of the body of a method?

Module `controller_mixins.rb`:

```
module ControllerMixin

  instance_eval "def search_by_vendor (*args) \n" \
    " @#{self.class.name.sub(/Controller/, '').tableize} = #{self.class.name.sub(/Controller/, '')}.find_all_by_vendor_id(params[:vendor_id])  \n"\
    "respond_to do |format| \n" \
    " format.html { render :template=>'/#{self.class.name.sub(/Controller/, '').tableize}/index',  :layout=>'vendor_info'} \n" \
    " format.xml  { render :xml => @#{self.class.name.sub(/Controller/, '').tableize} } \n" \
    "end \n"\
  "end \n"

end
```

class being mixed with:

```
class VendorOrdersController < ApplicationController
  # GET /vendor_orders
  # GET /vendor_orders.xml
  require 'controller_mixins'
  include ControllerMixin
 <rest of class>
```

So I'd like to see the implementation of the mixin when applied to `VendorOrdersController`
probably via `script/console` for convenience.

UPDATE:  Per @~/ I saved the string to a variable and `puts`'d it.  That worked perfectly.  Which brought to light an error in my code (the reason I wanted to see the code in the first place).  Code below is much better, and works as expected.

```
module ControllerMixin

  def self.included(mod)
     method_body = "def search_by_vendor \n" \
      " @#{mod.name.sub(/Controller/, '').tableize} = #{mod.name.sub(/Controller/, '')}.find_all_by_vendor_id(params[:vendor_id])  \n"\
      "respond_to do |format| \n" \
      " format.html { render :template=>'/#{mod.name.sub(/Controller/, '').tableize}/index',  :layout=>'vendor_info'} \n" \
      " format.xml  { render :xml => @#{mod.name.sub(/Controller/, '').tableize} } \n" \
      "end \n"\
    "end \n" 

    puts method_body
    mod.class_eval(method_body)
  end

end
```

Comment: You'll probably want to use 'here documents' (`CODE <<- ... CODE`) instead of concatenated strings. The format is much nicer.

Comment: Why I have not heard of these 'here documents'  This is a GOD send.  Thank you.  Good explanation (on someone else's blog): http://blog.commonthread.com/2007/12/20/tip-ruby-here-document

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cannot get the source code behind a method.

The best you can do is get the `Method` object that represents the method using `Object#method`. For example:

```
m = VendorOrdersController.method(:search_by_vendor)
```

But you'll find that there's not much more than a `Method#name`, `Method#arity`, `Method#source_location`, etc.

In your case however, why not simply store the string in a variable, print it, before using `instance_eval`?

Regardless, your `instance_eval` will be executed at the moment of module declaration. You probably want to wrap it in an `included` callback to have it executed at the moment of inclusion.

```
module ControllerMixin
  def self.included(mod)
    mod.instance_eval([...])
  end
end
```

Comment: Sorry Shtééf, just noticed you made the the same point in the middle of your answer. I will leave mine for the moment as someone else might miss it as I did.

Comment: Can you not run `.method(:search_by_vendor).source`?

Answer (score 2):

The best way to ensure you get your intended output as a result ... is to write a test.

Also - i don't approve of using instance_eval like that. If you MUST metaprogram like that, use `define_method`, or you could probably get away without doing any of that by passing a parameter from the routes, sure, it's a little more typing, but that much metaprogramming is just icky.

Comment: I looks like define_method basically promotes a block to a method.  Given that I won't know my method name or internal variables, how can I define this as a block generally enough?

Comment: @SooDesuNe: Because the block you give to `define_method` is a closure, you will have access to the local variables. Just try it; in your case it's trivial and will be **much** nicer.

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't you assign the string to a variable before instance_eval runs and output it to the console?

As your string defines the whole method you essentially already have the source code.

Answer (score 0):

as above answers say, the best way to do what you are trying to do is with define_method.

if anyone is looking for "Meta-programming: output method body as text" try this:

if you want to get the code of a class or a method check out [ParseTree](http://rubygems.org/gems/ParseTree)
and [ruby2ruby](http://rubygems.org/gems/ruby2ruby)

ParseTree can grab the Abstract Syntax Tree of a class or method and generates "symbolic expressions", like lisp, it looks likes lists of lists of symbols, and is very interesting.

ruby2ruby takes these s-exps and turns it into regular ruby.

be warned, ParseTree does not currently work in ruby 1.9.